# How can I remove 'Administrator' FullAccess from all mailboxes in one hit?

Tags: exchange

I want to delete Administrator FullAccess permission from all mailboxes in one hit.

Is it possible to do it with PowerShell in Exchange Management Shell?

Comment: Your backup will use what account to run ?

Comment: We don't back up individual mailboxes, we backup the database.

Answer (score 1):

Never tested, but will be like that;

> Get-Mailbox -Server “servername” | Remove-MailboxPermission -User
>   administrator -AccessRights FullAccess -inheritancetype all

I'am not sure the impact it will have too, so run it at your own risk. For granular restore and such operation.